# Why does this sentence have to be inserted in C?

Tags: reading-comprehension

The passage below is part of an article about evolution of birds. And I had to choose where the sentence:

> “Furthermore, migration allows birds to avoid climates that are too hot or too cold during certain seasons.”

has to be placed in the paragraph.

> A. Flight provides numerous benefits. B. It enhances hunting and scavenging; many birds consume flying insects, an abundant, highly nutritious food resource. C. Flight also provides ready escape from earthbound predators and enables some birds to migrate great distances to exploit different food resources and seasonal breeding areas. D.

I chose D as the answer without much thinking because it seemed like an obvious choice to me but the book says the answer is C.
Can you explain to me why the sentence has to be inserted in C?

Comment: So what is the option in D? You did not write that.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. A, B, C, D are the possible places where the sentence “Furthermore, ~” could be inserted!

Comment: It sounds like the question is ambiguous. If you choose C, does that mean that you insert the sentence before C or after C?

Comment: @Ben, I think you insert it _at_ C.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely go with D.

The third sentence talks about additional benefits of "flight". It says that "flight" allows birds to escape predators and migrate great distances [for some specific reasons]. And "migration" allows them to avoid undesirable climate.

"D" is where your sentence fits in perfectly as

> “Furthermore, migration allows birds to avoid climates that are too hot or too cold during certain seasons.”

talks about what "migration" further allows birds to do [more specific reasons].

"D" makes the paragraph flow smoothly. There is consistency between the ideas:  *"benefits of flight" -> "hunting", "escaping from predators", "migration" -> "benefits of migration" -> "different food resources", "seasonal breeding areas", and "avoid bad climates"*

Answer (score 0):

Placing at D would not be incorrect.  Placing it at the end would seem as natural as inserting at C. I suspect the person setting the question was thinking that it would be incorrect to introduce "migration", and then have a "Furthermore..." sentence on the topic of migration.  That does not seem to be a valid objection, and you could object to placing at C for the same reason: The topic of migration would be introduced, dropped, and then introduced again. That makes understanding harder for the reader.  But these are minor points of stylistic judgement, and not something where a clear "rule" is being applied.

Either C or D are possible.